# Amazon automatically deletes a S3 Bucket

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm making an RDP application, using the Amazon S3 Bucket service, to store images for viewing, and later deletion.

My current flow is as follow:

1. I take a screenshot of the computer screen
2. I then take this screenshot and upload it to my S3 Bucket as a JPEG.
3. After this image has been viewed, I will make a **DeleteObjectRequest** to delete this image.

This whole process, is repeated once every half a second. So this doesn't actually store the images for very long, only the transfer rate is high.

This process also only runs, when the RDP Service I made is enabled, which could range from 30 seconds to 5 minutes. (So that's maximum of 600 upload requests, and 600 delete requests).

Now, taking into consideration these conditions, why would Amazon delete my Bucket automatically? Is this a restriction, an automatic abuse-mechanism or is it simply a bug?

What could I do to prevent this?

**Upload code I use**

```
TransferUtility aws = new TransferUtility(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

aws.Upload(imageFile, bucketName, imageKey + ".jpg");
```

**Delete request code I use**

```
var dor = new DeleteObjectRequest();
dor.Key = key;
dor.BucketName = bucketName;

Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client sc = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(accessKeyId, secretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);
var response = sc.DeleteObject(dor);
```

Comment: AWS doesn't automatically delete S3 buckets. Something else is going on. What exactly leads you to think the bucket is being deleted?

Comment: @MarkB Because it get's removed/deleted from my S3 ? It's no longer there, and this has happened twice.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen when does the bucket get deleted? When you delete an object? And then the next upload fails?

Comment: @Mahdi I really can't tell. It just happens at some point. I've even noticed it got deleted when I didn't make any requests what so ever.

Comment: Turn on [AWS CloudTrail](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-getting-started.html), wait for the bucket to disappear again, then look at the CloudTrail logs and look for the `DeleteBucket` API call. It will show which User/Role made the API request to delete the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of AWS deleting buckets proactively -  but there are limits on how many buckets you can create (I believe it is 100 without increasing an account override).

I do question why you keep creating and deleting buckets however - I would think you would be better of creating a bucket and then adding and deleting objects within that bucket, instead of deleting the bucket itself. There is no charge for having an empty bucket, if that is your concern.

Also, make sure the region you are creating the bucket in, is the same place you are looking to see the bucket - just in case you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't too clear in my answer. I don't actually create and delete buckets, but only the objects INSIDE the 1 bucket.

Comment: So is your bucket disappearing, or the images in the bucket?

Comment: E.J Brennan, the bucket is disappearing.